# unable to connect to mysql running on my mac

Tags: mysql, docker, go

I am using golang app , wrapped up in a docker container to connect to mysql db running on my localhost(not container). Her eis what I tried:
Docker File

```
FROM artifactory.cloud.com//golang:1.10-alpine3.7

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.kdc.mafsafdfsacys.com/perfGo/
WORKDIR /go/src/github.kdc.mafsafdfsacys.com/perfGo
COPY ./ $WORKDIR
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN go build

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
RUN ls
RUN chmod +x ./perfGo
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

perfGo.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@tcp(localhost:3306)/testdb")
    checkErr(err)
    _,dbErr := db.Exec("USE testdb")
    if err != nil {
        panic(dbErr)
    }

    // insert
    _, inErr := db.Query("INSERT INTO books VALUES('rewyrewryewwrewyt','dsfdsfs','fdsfasaf','55')")

    defer db.Close()
    // if there is an error inserting, handle it
    if inErr != nil {
        panic(inErr.Error())
    }

}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

entrypoint.sh

## !/usr/bin/env bash

./perfGo

Command am using to build is

```
docker build .
```

command used to run the container:
docker run -p 3306:3306 -ti

The error that I see is

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /go/src/github.kdc.capitalone.com/midnight-tokens/perfGo/perf.go:22 +0x1d4
```

If I run the binary without the container, it runs totally fine on my mac, but when I try to run it as part of docker container, it fails to connect

Comment: `localhost` is a technical term, and it's probably less confusing to say something like "running on my desktop" than "running on my localhost"...particularly since from the point of view of the container the server _isn't_ running on `localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is running in a container, and the database is on the host, then the address of the database from the container is obviously not `localhost` (That is the loopback device of the container).

If you are  using Docker For Mac, then you can use:

`"docker.for.mac.localhost:3306"` in place of `"localhost:3306"`

Comment: My goodness, that worked, one last step, what would that be if am running the app container on ubuntu based EC2 trying to connect to a database cluster Ip on 3306 , something like databaseclusterIP:3306

Comment: It would be the exact same configuration as if you were running it not in a container and the database was on a different host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have the database host to be something like this cluster-c3dpvouhxmjg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com. Now I see error as :
 panic: dial tcp: lookup cluster-c3dpvouhxmjg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com on 8.8.4.4:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:50209->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout